# How to access map fragment from main view

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-mapview

I have a java class that extends fragment and inflates an xml layout. Below is my code for that java class:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

/**
 * Created by Mike on 3/17/14.
 */
public class BreweryMap extends Fragment {

    public BreweryMap(){}

    String beerId = "";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_brewmap, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        //get user information
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
        String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);


        //call async to get breweries to add to


        GoogleMap mMap;
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


        //add url
        String url = "hmyURL";

        //send mMap over with async task
        new GetVisitedBreweries(getActivity(), mMap).execute(url);


        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Here is the xml layout that is being inflated:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

My null pointer error is coming from this line:

```
    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

After looking at my code this makes sense to me that **it is NULL because the fragment ID that it is looking for is in my rootView** which is stored on this line:

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_brewmap, container, false);
```

**How can I successfully access the map fragment from my rootView?**

I have tried:

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) rootView.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

and other combinations. I feel like I am close but not quite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing Fragment and SupportFragment. Use SupportFragment everywhere:

- In your layout: use `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`
- In onCreate(): use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: it does not like this:

        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

Comment: Awesome so actually with how I wrote my code, I just need to do your first bullet point.